# Use a window resource in a DataTemplate with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `DataTemplate` that is loading a list of ~7000 items in a list for a `combobox`. Currently the `ItemsSource` is bound to a property in the data context of the `DataTemplate`, however this means that for each instance of the `DataTemplate` the system is loading all 7k objects, which is slowing down the system by quite a bit.

Ideally I want to be able to load the list once and use it for all instances. The obvious solution to me is using a resource defined in the `Window.Resources` section. However I can't figure out how this should work, and more importantly, how that resource should be populated via the MVVM pattern.

Current code which loads the `ItemsSource` for each `DataTemplate` instance

```
<DataTemplate>          
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" />          
</DataTemplate>
```

Attempt at solving the problem:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>           
        <sys:Object x:Key="ItemItemsSource"  />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<DataTemplate>          
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemItemsSource}}" />          
</DataTemplate>
```

## Update

Each DataTemplate has its own DataContext which means each instance of the data template has its own `ItemsSource`, which will populate at DataContext initialiser.

## Update 2

The ideal way in my mind to solve this is to have a property in the `DataContext`/VM of the Window that they Combobox is bound too. Is this possible? Something like:

```
public class WindowsViewModel
{
     public List<Object> SharedItemSource { get; set; }
}

<DataTemplate>          
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding <Some Binding To SharedItemSource>}" />          
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Comboboxes with 7000 items is usually not the way to go, can you use something like textbox with dropdown suggestions while typing.

Comment: if you have property defined in VM, then that will be loading just once and be served as source for all the comboboxes.. not every combobox does not create its itemsSource.. it just consume it to generate its item..

Comment: as i understand it each combobox has it's own VM .. 
so in each VM you need to populate the entire ItemSource .. 
Why not use a global repository , a static class which holding a collection to bind to , did i understand the situation correctly ?

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 That doesn't solve my problem in any way.

Comment: @eranotzap That is correct. Each DataTemplate has its own Context. I don't want an application wide static resource, just for the window. I can't figure out how to do that though

Comment: all your comboboxs are not in the same window , right , it's kinda hard to understand the situation your presenting , a DataTemplate for what Type is your DataTemplate for , and where and in what manner do youj use that type ?

Comment: Yes all the comboboxes are displayed on the same window

Comment: I won't use any of offered solutions, because it will reduce performance for your application. Try to do like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835472/wpf-what-can-cause-a-combobox-to-not-virtualize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a MainViewModel for your window or what ever control all your combobox's are in ,

cs:

```
 public class MainViewModel
 {
    private List<object> _itemsSource;

    public List<object> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return _itemsSource; }
        set { _itemsSource = value; }
    }                
 }
```

xaml:

```
       <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ItemsSource,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: if you are using it in an items control do : 

AncestorType=ItemsControl

Comment: additionally you should listen to flo's advice and use a VirtualizingStackPanel for 7000 items

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it has answered the question that I posed, however I have used a combination of this code, and Flo's to solve the problem. Using this shared ItemSource the problem of loading the window was fixed, but there was still a slowdown when opening the combo box. Flo's code solved the latter problem.

Comment: i know i commented above that you should use the VirtualizingStackPanel as flo suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the slow down ?

If it is when you show the ComboBox's popup, maybe you can try to use virtualization like this :

```
<DataTemplate>          
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ComboBox> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: The slowdown is because of the fact that when there are 10 instances of the `DataTemplate` there are 70,000 objects loaded.

Comment: Could you explain more what your VM contains ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Flo, this did help me in the end

Answer (score 0):

If you have property defined in VM, then that will be loading just once when you will be instantiating it and be served as source for all the comboboxes.. not every combobox create its itemsSource.. it just consume it to generate its items.. so whether you put your itemsSource as Resource or in Datacontext is one and the same thing here.

Comment: The `DataContext` of the DataTemplate is different for each row/DataTemplate.